# Error with ConTeXt and pgfplots 3d

Tags: pgfplots, context, tikz-3dplot

I have an old document I'm trying to recompile, and a 3d plot doesn't work anymore. I reduced it to the following MWE :

```
\usemodule[tikz]
\usemodule[pgfplots]
\pgfplotsset{compat=1.18}

\starttext

\starttikzpicture[scale=1]
  \startaxis[
    xmin=0, xmax=10, ymin=2, ymax=8, ticks=none,
  ]
    \addplot3 [surf, shader=interp, domain=0:10] { (x-5)^2 };
  \stopaxis
\stoptikzpicture

\stoptext
```

and I get the following error pointing to the `\stopaxis` command :

```
A prefix should be followed by a quantity that can be assigned to. Intermediatespaces and \relax tokens are gobbled in the process.
```

It seems related to the internals of tikz, so I really don't know what to do… Is there a workaround ?

Thanks in advance,

Comment: The incompatibility appears to be with `shader=interp`. The example compiles without that option. I don't understand the pgfplot codebase to understand what is going wrong.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The following patch appears to solve the problem:

```
diff --git a/texmf-modules/tex/generic/pgfplots/pgfplotsmeshplothandler.code.tex b/texmf-modules/tex/generic/pgfplots/pgfplotsmeshplothandler.code.tex
index 60d6274..106c490 100644
--- a/texmf-modules/tex/generic/pgfplots/pgfplotsmeshplothandler.code.tex
+++ b/texmf-modules/tex/generic/pgfplots/pgfplotsmeshplothandler.code.tex
@@ -2804,6 +2804,9 @@
                \def\pgfplotsretval{4}%
            \fi
        \fi
+       \if0\pgfplotsretval
+           \def\pgfplotsretval{5}
+       \fi
        \pgfkeyslet{/pgfplots/surf shading/shading type}\pgfplotsretval%
        %
        \pgfplotsplothandlermesh@set@shader@colormap
diff --git a/texmf-modules/tex/generic/pgfplots/sys/pgflibrarypgfplots.surfshading.pgfsys-luatex.def b/texmf-modules/tex/generic/pgfplots/sys/pgflibrarypgfplots.surfshading.pgfsys-luatex.def
index 0046daa..b563732 100644
--- a/texmf-modules/tex/generic/pgfplots/sys/pgflibrarypgfplots.surfshading.pgfsys-luatex.def
+++ b/texmf-modules/tex/generic/pgfplots/sys/pgflibrarypgfplots.surfshading.pgfsys-luatex.def
@@ -61,7 +61,7 @@
        \pgfplotslibrarysurfusepath
        \endpgfpicture
    }%
-   \immediate\saveboxresource resources{
+   \saveboxresource resources{
        /Pattern << \pgfplots@glob@TMPa >> % write the pattern resource dictionary
    }\pgfutil@tempboxa
    \leavevmode
```

Then, the following document compiles successfully:

```tex
\usemodule[tikz]
\usemodule[pgfplots]
\pgfplotsset{compat=1.18}

\startTEXpage[offset=1dk]
\starttikzpicture
    \startaxis
        \addplot3 [surf, shader=interp, domain=0:10] { (x-5)^2 };
    \stopaxis
\stoptikzpicture
\stopTEXpage
```

[image: output]

Comment: I don't really understand how I should apply this patch. Do I open the source code on my machine and change the relevant lines or do I make a git request for the update ?

Comment: @A.Licari-Guillaume If you're using LMTX standalone, you can paste the patch in some file `<file.patch>`, `cd` to the top-level `tex/` folder, then run `git apply <file.patch>`. Or, you can just edit the two files manually since the changes are pretty short.

Comment: Thank you, that works perfectly !